# Problemas en mysql workbench“Error Code: 1005.(errno: 150 ”Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed“)”

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create database Liga_Aguila;
use Liga_Aguila;
create table Presidente (
ID int (10), 
Nombre varchar (30), 
Nacimiento date, 
Edad int (2), 
Año_Elección int (4),
Cod_Equip int (6),
primary key (ID), foreign key (Cod_Equip) references Estadio(Codig_Equip));


create table Estadio(Codig_Equip int (6), 
Nombre_Equip varchar (40), 
Estadio varchar (40), 
Espectadores int (5), 
Inauguracion date, 
Ciudad varchar (20), 
primary key (Codig_Equip));
create table Jugador(Codigo_Jugador int(3),
ID int(10),
Nombre varchar(40),
Fecha_Nacimiento date,
Edad int(2),
Posicion varchar(20),
Equipo int(6),
primary key (Codigo_Jugador), foreign key (Equipo) references Estadio(Codig_Equip));


create table Partido (Cod_Partido int(3),
Fecha date,
Gol_Local int (2),
Gol_Visitante int (2),
Eq_Local int (2),
Eq_Visitante int (2),
primary key (Cod_Partido), foreign key (Eq_Local) references Estadio(Codig_Equip), foreign key (Eq_Visitante) references Estadio(Codig_Equip));


create table Goles (Jugador int(2),
Partido int(2),
Minuto int(3),
Tipo_Gol varchar(20),
foreign key (Jugador) references Jugador(ID), foreign key (Partido) references Partido(Cod_Partido));
```

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `liga_aguila`.`goles` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Answer (score 1):

- Primer error: Tu tabla `Presidente` hace referencia con una llave foránea a la tabla `Estadio`, pero esta misma no existe sino hasta después de `Presente`, por lo cual falla por que no encuentra la columna con la que tratas de hacer la vinculación.
- En la tabla `Jugador` tu llave primaria debería ser el `id` pues tu al momento tienes a `Cod_jugador`
- La vinculación entre tus tablas por medio del `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY` debe ser vinculando a la `PK` de la tabla principal con una equivalente de la tabla dependiente
- Idealmente mantén el mismo tipo de dato y longitud, pues mientras en una tabla tu llave primaria es: **`INT(3)`** luego tu llave foránea es **`INT(2)`**

Me parece que así ya debería funcionarte:

```
create database Liga_Aguila;
use Liga_Aguila;

create table Estadio(Codig_Equip int (6), 
    Nombre_Equip varchar (40), 
    Estadio varchar (40), 
    Espectadores int (5), 
    Inauguracion date, 
    Ciudad varchar (20), 
primary key (Codig_Equip));


create table Presidente (
    ID int (10), 
    Nombre varchar (30), 
    Nacimiento date, 
    Edad int (2), 
    Año_Elección int (4),
    Cod_Equip int (6),
primary key (ID), foreign key (Cod_Equip) references Estadio(Codig_Equip));


create table Jugador(
    Codigo_Jugador int(3),
    ID int(10),
    Nombre varchar(40),
    Fecha_Nacimiento date,
    Edad int(2),
    Posicion varchar(20),
    Equipo int(6),
primary key (ID), foreign key (Equipo) references Estadio(Codig_Equip));


create table Partido (
    Cod_Partido int(3),
    Fecha date,
    Gol_Local int (2),
    Gol_Visitante int (2),
    Eq_Local int (2),
    Eq_Visitante int (2),
primary key (Cod_Partido), 
foreign key (Eq_Local) references Estadio(Codig_Equip), 
foreign key (Eq_Visitante) references Estadio(Codig_Equip));


create table Goles (
    Jugador INT(10),
    Partido INT(3),
    Minuto int(3),
    Tipo_Gol varchar(20),
foreign key (Jugador) references Jugador(ID),
foreign key (Partido) references Partido(Cod_Partido));
```